# How would I make my React search bar component render faster results and avoid any memory leaks?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

When I type in the search component I notice that there's a delay and after typing a few characters and after the 4th or 5th character I get a white screen and a message in my console stating *"Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function"*.

Any ideas on how I can go about this? My goal is to just have a search bar that's able to properly render all of the results when someone searches for either a movie or actor.

This is the code for the interface:

```
export interface ActorAttributes {
    TYPE?: string,
    NAME?: string,
}

export interface MovieAttributes {
    OBJECTID: number,
    SID: string,
    NAME: string,
    DIRECTOR: string,
    DESCRIP: string,
```

App.tsx code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { searchMovies, searchActors, MovieAttributes, ActorAttributes } from "@utils/atts"

const Home: React.FC = () => {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState(false);
    const [movieSearch, setMovieSearch] = useState<MovieAttributes[]>([]);
    const [actorSearch, setActorSearch] = useState<ActorAttributes[]>([]);
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
            setSearch(true);

            let newMovieSearch = [...movieSearch];

            searchMovies(searchTerm).then(results => {
                newMovieSearch = results;
                setMovieSearch(results);
            });

            searchActors(searchTerm, newMovieSearch[1].SID).then(results => {
                setActorSearch(results);
            });

            setSearch(false);
        }
    }, [searchTerm]);

    const handleSearchTermChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={searchTerm} onChange={handleSearchTermChange} />
            {search && <p>Searching...</p>}
            {movieSearch.length > 0 && <p>Found {movieSearch.length} movies</p>}
            {actorSearch.length > 0 && <p>Found {actorSearch.length} actors</p>}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Currently I'm only able to type 2-3 character in my search bar before it starts to delay and/or I would recieve an error message in my console. I'm new to react and this is my first time ever creating a search component so if anyone has any tips, ideas, suggestions, etc. please feel free to leave a comment. Thanks to anyone who took the time to read my post :)

```
<div className="App">
     <ul className="posts">
        <input type="text" onChange={handleSearchTermChange} />
        {movieSearch.map((movie) => {
            if (searchTerm == "" || movie.NAME.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
                return (
                    <li key={movie.OBJECTID}>
                        <h3>{movie.NAME}</h3>
                        <p>{movie.DIRECTOR}</p>
                        <p>{movie.DESCRIP}</p>
                    </li>
                );
             }
            return null;
        )}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: A big factor is how large the set you're searching is. If it's small enough you should do a synchronous search wrapped in `useMemo`. If it's larger (say at least 50-100k items) you might want to look at using `useEffect` instead and make it async. But then you should also add some kind of throttling and make sure you cancel any outdated/stale searches as soon as possible.

Comment: Rendering large sets to the screen is also expensive, so pagination is a good idea. Or virtual table implementations can be a solution. But I would look at some existing libraries for that instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

As the others saids, if the result of the Api calls are too large you may get problems, try to prevent sending the query if you know many results will be thrown (i.e if the string is less than less say 3 characters). Alongside with this you can use `debounce` or `throttle` functions from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) to prevent updating the state on every key stroke.

Like this:

```js
  const delayedQuery = useCallback(
    _.debounce((searchTerm: string) => sendQuery(searchTerm), 500),
    []
  );
```

Example sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/debounce-lodash-ivtm1p?file=/src/App.tsx:1508-1623

Answer (score 0):

I think guess your problems. dear there is details explaination about this console message **"Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function"** i will try my best to explain too short there and sorry for that.

**problem:** after typing 4th to 5th character get white screen.

**why:** when you typing something, for each character update the "searchTerm" state after updating this state run useEffect for every character and inside useEffect callback have promise function, they are async function and for this reason crash your hole application.

**solution short explain:** there is no need any useEffect. you can directly use promise function inside onChange handler function as like your "handleSearchTermChange". see my little code solution. i hope you get your solution idea from this little code.

```js
const handleSearchTermChange = (event: any): void => {
    const value = event.target.value;

    if (value.trim() !== "") {
      axios
        .get(`https://example.com/api/v1/product/search?searchProduct=${value}&fields=name`)
        .then((res) => {
          setOptions(res.data.result);
        })
        .catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
    }
  };
```

after got promise result you can store this data in state. i don't know your hole purpose that's why i did't write here other logic. if you face any problem to understand please write comment.